# Generating all possible edge permutations for a given number of nodes in a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, matlab

My problem is best explained using an example. Suppose we have a graph of $6$ vertices. I would like to generate all the possible edge combinations this graph would have, including the graph with zero edges. Is it right to say that the number of possible combinations would be $6!$?

Is there an existing algorithm recursive or iterative which outputs such a list of combinations for example on MATLAB?

I require this because I am trying to build an algorithm which outputs all possible combinations of a neural network given the number of layers and edges, so this would indeed require some further conditions applied upon it, but I imagine that the upperbound for the number of possibilites should not exceed $6!$.

Comment: There are 6 choose 2 (15) edges in the complete graph on 6 vertices.  If you want all possible subsets of those edges then you'd have 2^15 graphs (many will be isomorphic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, for a graph with $n$ nodes, there will be $$\large 2^{n \choose 2} = 2^\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ distinct labeled graphs. Of course, relabeling will indeed show that many are equivalent. [This](https://oeis.org/A000088) sequence on OEIS lists the number of isomorphism types.

To my knowledge, Matlab doesn't have the kind of functionality your'e looking for. However, [Sage](http://sagemath.org) does. (Well, it can generate all isomorphism types of graphs, which I'm sure can be tweaked to only list their edges, if you want). Here's their [documentation](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph.html) on undirected graphs. A statement like,

> for g in graphs(5):

would let you work each representative of isomorphism classes of graphs with $5$ nodes, one at a time. There are quite a few of these for large values of $n$, so don't expect things to go too quickly!

Comment: What do you mean when you say many are equivalent? Do you mean that a graph of 6 nodes and one edge on any pair would count as one? Because in my case I am also counting the cases for the edge being on the other pairs.

Comment: @jablesauce Yes, that is what I meant; that all graphs with $6$ nodes and $1$ edge would fall into the same 'isomorphism class', and count as $1$ graph, in certain situations. If you don't want them to be the same, that's good and bad news: They're easier to generate, but there are far far more graphs if you don't condense the isomorphic ones into a single representative. For $6$ nodes, there are $2^{15} \approx 32,000$ labeled graphs, that condense into only $156$ isomorphism classes!

Comment: Fortunately the upper bound for the specific models I am studying is only around 512 for 6 nodes, for 8 nodes it will grow exponentially but I will not consider all cases.

Answer (score 0):

[Found issue with my reasoning] Possible permutations of graph with N vertices should be $2^{n^2 - N}$ given it's a labeled graph and no renaming of vertices?

### My reasoning:

1. There are a total of $n*{n-1}$ possible edges where n is total vertices.
   This is because every node can connect with every other node. Example: each node has 6 edges in a graph with 7 vertices. Total edges would be $7 * 6$ or $n*(n-1)$
2. Per each possible edge, the edge either does exist in the graph or does not.
3. That gives us a binary variable for each possible connection.
4. Each addition of a binary choice will double your total permutations. Example: if I have two coins, both can be heads, both can be tails, 1 is heads and the other is tails, or vice versa. That gives you $2^2$ permutations or configurations of the coins. If there were just one coin, it would be $2^{1}$ permutations.
5. So where p is possible edges $2^{p}$ is the total permutations of the graph
6. That gives us $2^{n^2 - n}$

### Update:

I now think $2^{\frac{n^2 - n}{2}}$ is the correct answer
Half of the vertices in such a enumeration are redundant. My math would be correct for directed graphs but not for not directed graphs.
This code I put together highlighted my error:
https://play.golang.com/p/bhxWMiFLpsq

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Notice that there already exists an accepted answer. Since your result is different from the one therein, let us check if it stands a chance of being correct. If $n=1$, how many non-isomorphic graphs can you generate with it? Two: one is formed with the vertex itself and no edges, the other with the vertex and a single edge ("loop"). Using your formulae, though, you get 1, not 2, so you must be mistaken. Instead of trying to answer the question, why don't you take the time to understand the accepted answer?

Comment: Thanks @Alex Good advice. I forgot that vertices can connect to themselves 